# Weird DeclareUnicodeCharacter / siunitx clash

Tags: siunitx, unicode, input-encodings, xfrac

I love declaring unicode characters to write readable formulas. However, I just ran into a strange issue. The following works as expected, with the “×” sign being replaced with the chosen code (“plop”):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D7}{plop}

\begin{document}
×
\end{document}
```

However, if I add the `siunitx` package, which seems completely unrelated, I get an error stating that `\texttimes` is undefined:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D7}{plop}

\begin{document}
×
\end{document}
```

It then gets even stranger: if I add the even-more-unrelated package `xfrac` (the order does not seem to matter), it works again:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xfrac}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D7}{plop}

\begin{document}
×
\end{document}
```

Sure, this could be considered as a solution, but I cannot feel satisfied with something that I don't understand at all.
Also, note that with certain combinations of packages that I have yet to pin down, the error turns to “Command `\texttimes` unavailable in encoding T1.” instead.
Furthermore, this does not seem to be limited to “×” at all. The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{siunitx}
%\usepackage{xfrac}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{\ensuremath{^2}}

\begin{document}
$x²$
\end{document}
```

gives an “Undefined control sequence.” error for `\texttwosuperior` unless `siunitx` is removed or `xfrac` is added.
Note that the same thing seems to occur when using the `newunicodechar` package to declare the characters instead.

What's wrong with the considered code when using `siunitx` but not `xfrac`?

Comment: Very compliments for your question.+1

Comment: Very compliments for your question.+1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, `siunitx` needs to set up some minimal character support from the `TS1` range. This is done such that loading `textcomp` is not forced:

```
\DeclareFontEncoding{TS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{TS1}{cmr}{m}{n}
```

followed by a number of declarations for specific symbols. However, this will lead to LaTeX looking for approach `TS1` symbols for other characters made active before it was set up. Thus there is a timing issue: you've made the character active before the 'minimal' `TS1` support is set up. (The minimal support in `siunitx` only defines such symbols as are absolutely required.)

You can fix this most easily by loading `textcomp`, or by altering the definition of the custom chars after loading `siunitx`. (The `xfrac` package loads `textcomp`, which is why it solves the problem.)

Comment: Wow, thanks. I'm not sure I get what you mean by “altering the definition of the custom chars” though. And I never had to explicitly include `textcomp` so I don't even know what it was written for, haha. `texdoc` just points me towards `encguide.pdf` and `source2e.pdf`.

Comment: It is no exactly clear what happens really because the OP's `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter` usage was after loading `siunitx`.

Comment: @jfbu siunitx setups the encoding at begin document. And then the code from inputenc/utf8.def loads `ts1enc.dfu` also at begin document. As `ts1enc.dfu` contains `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D7}{\texttimes}` the other definition is overwritten. (But you are right, loading siunitx early doesn't work, one need to load textcomp).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer then perhaps simply `\AtBeginDocument{\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B2}{\ensuremath{^2}}}` after loading siunitx ? (or same with `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00D7}{plop}`) (does work in my brief testing)

Comment: (don't copy paste from my comment, the site adds U+200B and U+200C invisible chars -- really irritating)